# Does GridDb have Management Views for query history?

Tags: griddb

There are many tutorials with crud operations and other concepts, but I was wondering if there was a way to get information on the historical executions of queries. Other DB platforms like SQL server tend to have "System" views which store metrics.

I would like to get the longest running operations performed in Gridb, is there a view I can use?

I tried accessing systems views or linux service logs but did not find the information I was looking for. I also tried reviewing the documentation, no specific call out stood out to me.

Answer (score 0):

These sorts of logs should be in the GS_LOG directory. If you switch to the `gsadm` user and find the home directory (default is `/var/lib/gridstore`), the log directory in there has logs for all matter of GridDB activity.

Specifically if you look at the gridstore log, it may give some of that important information that you're looking for